# Сложение GMT времени в PHP

Tags: php, время, datetime

Доброго времени суток. Из JS скрипта получаю дату в GET запросе в формате "2018-02-15 01:21:00 GMT+0200" - как можно прибавить к этой дате нужное количество минут/часов/дней с сохранением формата?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$d = '2018-02-15 01:21:00 GMT+0200';

$date = new \DateTime($d);
$date->modify("+ 2 day + 5 hours + 10 minutes");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Использовал Ваш вариант. В начале файла еще добавил `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');` , ибо ошибку выдавало.

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = '2018-02-15 01:21:00 GMT+0200';

$nd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($d . "+ 2 day + 5 hours + 10 minutes"));
```